# Angularjs not updating a label given by angular template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have an element given its title/label with angularjs

```
 <a ng-click="addCounter()" class="btn btn-sm btn-default">{{(($scope.addingCounter)?'Save':'Add')}}</a>
```

When page is refreshed button has Save or Add title according to the addingCounter variable. When clicked on button, addCounter function changes the addingCounter variable. But Button label is not changed.

this the method in controller

```
 $scope.addingCounter = false;
 $scope.addCounter = function () {
        $scope.addingCounter = !$scope.addingCounter;
 };
```

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `$scope` from the template:

```
{{addingCounter?'Save':'Add'}}
```

You had reference to `$scope.addingCounter` of the controller's `$scope` object (like `$scope.$scope.addingCounter`). AngularJS couldn't find such object, and by default it put *falsy* value. That's why you saw `Add`.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `$scope` from the template and if it don't work you could use the `$scope.$apply` function:

```
$scope.addCounter = function () {
    $scope.$apply(function () {
        $scope.addingCounter = !$scope.addingCounter;
    });
};
```

[You could see more here.](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html)